# Devicetree parallel CSI OV7670

Tags: device-tree

I'm currently trying to get an image with fswebcam out of my OV7670 camera, but I only get a completly green image. 
Could you look over my devicetree if I made some obvious mistakes? 
board-file.dts:

```
&csi1 {
status = "okay";
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&csi1_pins>;
port {
/* Parallel bus endpoint */
csi1_ep: endpoint {
    remote-endpoint = <&ov7670_0>;
    bus-width = <8>;    
If hsync-active/vsync-active are missing,
       embedded BT.656 sync is used */
            hsync-active = <0>; /* Active low */
            vsync-active = <0>; /* Active low */
            data-active = <1>;  /* Active high */
            pclk-sample = <1>;  /* Rising */ 


        };
     };
  };

&i2c1 {
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins>;
pinctrl-names = "default";
status = "okay";


ov7670: camera@21 {
    compatible = "ovti,ov7670";
    reg = <0x21>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&csi1_mclk>;
    clocks = <&ccu CLK_CSI1_MCLK>;
    clock-names = "xclk";
    assigned-clock-rates = <24000000>;

    port {
        ov7670_0: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&csi1_ep>;
            /* If hsync-active/vsync-active are missing,
       embedded BT.656 sync is used */
            hsync-active = <0>; /* Active low */
            vsync-active = <0>; /* Active low */
            data-active = <1>;  /* Active high */
            pclk-sample = <1>;  /* Rising */



           };
       };
    };
 };
    &pio {
    csi1_pins: csi1-pins@0 {
        pins     = 
    "PE0","PE2","PE3","PE4","PE5","PE6","PE7","PE8","PE9","PE10","PE11";
        function = "csi";
     };

     csi1_mclk: csi1-mclk@0 {
        pins = "PE1";
        function = "csi";
       };

     i2c1_pins: i2c1 {
    pins = "PE21", "PE22";
    function = "i2c1";
   };
 };
```

Proccesor-file.dtsi:

```
csi1: csi@1cb4000 {
        compatible = "allwinner,sun8i-v3s-csi";
        reg = <0x01cb4000 0x1000>;
        interrupts = <GIC_SPI 84 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
        clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_CSI>,
        <&ccu CLK_CSI1_SCLK>,
        <&ccu CLK_DRAM_CSI>;
        clock-names = "bus", "mod", "ram";
        resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_CSI>;
        status = "disabled";
    };
```